# Android - how to place one fragment on another

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am looking for a hint/way how to achieve such a "layout" in android. What I have so far is layout of mainActivity, on which is embedded fragment A. What I wanna do, is place above fragment A next one (Fragment B). For better illustration image is included.
[image]

How should I implement such a composition ? Also, after click on "Save" it should process inserted information a fragment should be hidden/removed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use DialogFragment. You may refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) or this [tutorial](http://www.yousaytoo.com/dialogfragment-with-interface-to-pass-data-back-to-activity/3059669)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create layout (your editview and button), e.g. `fragment_register_account.xml`
2. Inflate the layout in a class e.g. `RegisterAccountDialog` that extend `DialogFragment`

> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_account, container);
>     mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
>     getDialog().setTitle("Hello");
>
>    return view;
> }
> ```

3.Register onClick to your 'Create new Account' button and show the DialogFragment.

> ```
>     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
>     RegisterAccountDialog dialog = new RegisterAccountDialog();
>     dialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
> ```

A good tutorial [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)